# I'm unable to install JDK 12 (Java SE12) No source to download

Tags: java, java-12

I'm trying to download Java SE 12 or JDK 12 but there's no longer a link to download that:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html

It says:

> "Java SE 12 Downloads
>
> Java SE 12 has reached end of support. Users of Java SE 12 should
>   switch to Java SE 13.
>
> Please visit our Java SE Downloads page to get the current version of
>   Java SE.
>
> You will be redirected to the Java SE Downloads page in 20 seconds.
>   Please update your bookmarks to the Java SE Downloads page. "

And looking for downloads you only are able to download Java SE11 or Java SE13 (12 is not in the list)

Do anybody knows why is this situation? 
I'm cloning a Project that's in Java 12, should I migrate to Java 13 instead?

Comment: Yes, migrate to Java-13. The link itself reads and I quote "*Java SE 12 has reached end of support. Users of Java SE 12 should switch to Java SE 13.*"

Comment: To add to @Naman's comment, there are two long term support versions of java right now 8 and 11.  It is recommended to use one of these versions unless there is a specific reason to be on one of the short term releases (9, 10, 12, 13, etc...).

Comment: I didn't know about short term releases, I thought there always would be long term releases and Java 8 had a particular exception, now it makes sense why do I see too much Projects in Java 8.
Do you know where may I see the short term versions and it's support times?

Comment: Don't use Java 12. If you absolutely have to, go to the section "Java Archive" at the very bottom of the official Oracle download page.

Comment: You can still download it from https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Naman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118/naman) and [Hooknc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42962/hooknc) you are right.
I add this as a valid answer beacause I don't find how to mark your comment as an answer.

The main part is:

> Yes, migrate to Java-13. The link itself reads and I quote *"Java SE
>   12 has reached end of support. Users of Java SE 12 should switch to
>   Java SE 13."*

And

> To add to @Naman's comment, there are two long term support versions
>   of java right now 8 and 11. It is recommended to use one of these
>   versions unless there is a specific reason to be on one of the short
>   term releases (9, 10, 12, 13, etc...).

Basically is better to use Java 8 or 11 for a long term project and you're able to use current brand new Java version having in mind that you may need to update/migrate to newer version if it's a Short Term Release.